# Substring help...?

Tags: jquery, user-interface

I sit possible to search from a particular word using substring() in js.

For ex: i have:

```
temp = "myself";
```

Is it possible to use:

```
substring("myself",...);
```

Comment: @David: So... Is it possible for me to copy the contents of the iframe into a temporary text file and then perform the required operation...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot interact with an iframe that loads another site (unless it's on the exact same domain) due to the [Same Origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)